# VSCode repeat actions to files

Tags: encoding, visual-studio-code

I have tons of files encoded in Japanese (Shift JIS).
Open these files in VSCode with default encoding UTF-8 displays gibberishes.

Following is actions I have to take to each file:

1. Reopen with Encoding
2. select Japanese (Shift JIS)
3. Save with Encoding
4. select UTF-8

Does VSCode have any build-in tool/extension can record those actions and apply them to all files in folder (include subfolders)?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I use shell script:

```
function encode() 
{
    iconv -f shift_jis -t utf-8 "$1" > test
    # iconv -f iso8859-15 -t utf8 "$1" > test;
    cat test > "$1";
}

function walk()  
{  
  for file in `ls $1`  
  do  
    local path=$1"/"$file  
    if [ -d $path ]  
     then  
      echo "DIR $path"  
      walk $path  
    else  
      echo "FILE $path"  
      encode $path
    fi      
  done  
}  

if [ $# -ne 1 ]  
then  
  echo "USAGE: $0 TOP_DIR"  
else  
  walk $1  
fi
```